# Single Measure in PowerBI - Divide filtered columns to produce percentage

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

I have a data set with cols (ID, Calc.CompleteBool where complete = 1 and incomplete = 0) of the form:

```
    ID | Calc.CompleteBool
----------------------------
    100| 1
    101| 0
    103| 1
    105| 1
```

I need to create a measure that gives me a single percentage complete. Thus, the measure needs to count the total number of IDs (n) and divide by that number the total IDs that meet the condition of 'complete' or 1.

E.g. 3 / 4 = 75%

I have tried the following and it does not work. It is returning a value of zero (0). Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Calc.pctComplete = 

VAR total_aps = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('TABLE_NAME'[ID]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('TABLE_NAME'),
        'TABLE_NAME'[Calc.CompleteBool] = 'TABLE_NAME'[Calc.CompleteBool]
    )
)

VAR total_aps_complete = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('TABLE_NAME'[Calc.CompleteBool]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('TABLE_NAME'),
        'TABLE_NAME'[Calc.CompleteBool] = 1
    )
)

RETURN total_aps_complete/total_aps
```

**Update**
I also need to add another filter in that only returns rows where "CheckID" = Yes.

There are 3,700 total IDs
There are ~ 1,500 IDs where CheckID = Yes
And roughly 8 where Calc.CompleteBool = 1

```
    ID | Calc.CompleteBool  | CheckID |
---------------------------------------
    100| 1                  | Yes
    101| 0                  | No
    103| 1                  | No
    105| 1                  | Yes
    106| 0                  | Yes
```

{100, 105, 106} are the set that would be included. So the division would be 2/3 = 66% complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result can be calculated with simple dax formula as following. The concept of `calculate with filter` can transform `count` into similar function like excel `countifs`:

```
Completion = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[ Calc.CompleteBool]),
                Sheet1[ Calc.CompleteBool]=1, Sheet1[CheckID]="Yes") / 
                    COUNT(Sheet1[ Calc.CompleteBool])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi - this doesn't work. It just produces 0. Multiply by 100 and it produces 1.

Comment: Are you data is misleading? As I perform the testing with correct answer??

Comment: I dont think the data is misleading? I looked at the raw data and there are 27 1's and 1500 0's. It's possible the 0 output is just too small to reflect? Is there a way to show the precision? 27/1500 = 0.018. I need to show 0.018%.

Comment: Yes it is correct, click on the `new measure` you create, and change the format of your measure to `2~5` decimal as you wish, then it will display `1.8%` for 27/1500.

Comment: This works. I totally forgot to change the precision. Now I just have to figure out why it's producing an unexpected value for my actual data :) Thank you!

Comment: Crud. I just realized I need another filter on the counts. I need not only CompleteBool = 1 but I also need CheckID = Yes. Can you help me out there?

Comment: You can add multiple filter to the `calculate` measure, see my edited answer :)

Comment: Thank you that's super helpful. Can I pass add'l filters in the denominator? I need the denominator to only  divide by the subset of all IDs where CheckID = Yes as well.

Comment: You may try `CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[ Calc.CompleteBool]), Sheet1[CheckID]="Yes")` for the total count instead of `COUNT(Sheet1[ Calc.CompleteBool])`, then it should give the percentage that you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

You may use this measure (add +0 to __completed if you want see 0% if all rows has 0 in Calc.CompleteBool either you get BLANK:

```
Percentage% = 
var __completed =  CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES(TABLE_NAME[ID])), 'TABLE_NAME'[Calc.CompleteBool] = 1) + 0
var __all = COUNTROWS('TABLE_NAME')

return

DIVIDE(__completed, __all)
```

Consider to use DIVIDE instead of "/" https://dax.guide/divide/

[image]
[image]